# How can I count the number of instances of this character at the end of a string in SQL or PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I've got a string that ends with a certain number of '=' characters at the end. It's basically a base 64 string.

How can I get this count of '=' characters at the end? A built-in SQL function or regex would be preferred.

I know about the `instr` function, but it doesn't seem like it could be applied here. I'm not sure if a regex would apply here either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `length` and `replace`

```
select length(some_column) - length(replace(some_column, '=', ''))
from your_table
```

Comment: Thanks! Ended up using select nvl(length(replace('hello world==', rtrim('hello world==', '='), '')), 0) padding
from dual

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT('hello world==', '=') cnt FROM dual
/


SELECT  count(distinct(Instr('hello world==','=', LEVEL))) cnt
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= Length('hello world==') 
ORDER BY 1
/
```

Comment: the first line counts all of the '=' not just the ones at the end e.g. regexp_count('==Hello world ==','=') returns 4. OP wants count of characters at end.